# How to disable a particular FormControl of a FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, angular14

I have this form:

```
this.myform= new FormGroup({
  ...
  customDetails: new FormArray([]),
});

  get customDetailsFormArray() {
    return this.shippingLocationDetailsUpdateForm.get(
      'customDetails'
    ) as FormArray;
  }

this.customDetailsFormArray.push(
  new FormGroup({
    customRegNumber: new FormControl(''),
    customCode: new FormControl(''),
    customRegistrationtype: new FormControl(''),
    customRegStartDate: new FormControl(''), // <----------- disable this when user clicks a button
    customRegEndDate: new FormControl(''),
  })
);

this.myform.enable();
```

I want to disable `customRegStartDate` when clicking a button. Rest should remain enabled.

I tried:

```
this.myform.get('customDetails.customRegStartDate')?.disable();
```

Tried this also:

```
Object.entries(this.myform.controls)
      .filter(
        ([key, value]) =>
          [
            'customDetails.customRegStartDate',
          ].indexOf(key) < 0
      )
      .forEach(([key, value]) => value.disable());
```

But the code is not working. Please help.

Comment: Are you try to disable the `customRegStartDate` control in only selected FormGroup within the FormArray? Or disable `customRegStartDate` controls in all FormGroup in FormArray?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the (`FormGroup`) index to disable the selected `customRegStartDate` for particular `FormGroup` in `customDetails` `FormArray`.

```
<button (click)="disableCustomRegStartDateControl(i)">Disable customRegStartDate control</button>
```

```
disableCustomRegStartDateControl(i: number) {
  this.shippingLocationDetailsUpdateForm
    .get(`customDetails.${i}.customRegStartDate`)
    ?.disable();
}
```

For disabling all `customRegStartDate` controls in `FormArray`:

```
disableAllCustomRegStartDateControl() {
  for (let formGroup of this.customDetailsFormArray.controls) {
    formGroup.get('customRegStartDate')?.disable();
  }
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jkusqj?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.myform.get('customDetails.customRegStartDate')?.disable();
```

I think `AbstractControl#get` doesn't work with these `.` separated queries for controls, but you have to query each level separately.

Additionally, `this.myform.get('customDetails')` will return a `FormArray`, which doesn't have a field `customRegStartDate`. You can get the controls with `FormArray#controls` ([docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#controls)).

Then, since with `this.customDetailsFormArray.push` you pushed a single item into that, you have to retrieve that with `[0]`, which should give you a `FormGroup`, the one that has the controls `customRegNumber`, `customCode`, etc, and also the one you are looking for: `customRegStartDate`.

On that you should be able to call `disable()`.

---

EDIT:
Maybe your snippet doesn't show all of the intricacies of the form, but you could possibly change `customDetails` from being a `FormArray` to be directly the `FormGroup` you currently push into that array, ie. you could remove the array level from the form hierarchy.